# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter

Tags: php, laravel, rate-limiting

I checked the other posts on Stack Overflow, but none of them resolved my issue.

I'm also still learning Laravel, so 100% beginner.

I follow the steps from [this article](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-9-installation-on-windows) to install it (`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`) and wanted to test out the `RateLimiter`.

But I keep getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter" not found

I made sure that `'RateLimiter' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::class'` is in the `config/app.php` (it wasn't there before, but it makes no difference).

This is the code that I'm testing, which comes from the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/rate-limiting#basic-usage).

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

$executed = RateLimiter::attempt(
    'send-message:',
    $perMinute = 5,
    function() {
        echo 'hi';
        // Send message...
    }
);

if (! $executed) {
    return 'Too many messages sent!';
}
```

I also tried to run `composer update` again to make sure everything was up to date, and checked if I could maybe download the `RateLimiter` package [here](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/), but I don't see it.

I do suspect the package is missing, but no idea how to fix, and all suggestions from other posts on Stack Overflow make no difference to me.

Any suggestions what I could check/do to fix this error?

Comment: How are you running that code? Keep in mind in order for any compose installed packages to load you need to include the autoloader first. [index.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/public/index.php#L34) in the laravel boilerplate app does this but if you don't run your code via a web route or artisan command you need to require this manually

Comment: @apokryfos I made the stupid mistake to call the php file that contains that code directly. I see now I need to go down the web route. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. 100% beginner with Laravel, which I guess shows :)